# Help: No Cycles render option on Steam release!

Tags: cycles-render-engine

I need Cycles render on so i can turn off MipMaps, But i Don't have the option to turn on Cycles Render! Please Help me!

Comment: what version of blender are you using? Is the cycles addon enabled?

Comment: I am using version 2.79, The latest Non-Beta/Alpha Version on steam.